# How to implement a Forward proxy server?

Tags: proxy, webserver, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I have a requirement whose architecture involves the following components.

1. A (Client)
2. B (Proxy)
3. C (Destination Server(s))

I would like to forward all web requests from A's browser through a proxy set up in B to the appropriate destination server. In another words, if the user wants to visit Google on A, the requests should be forwarded via B to the destination server(Google). The proxy on B should be able to forward requests to various destination servers based on the request originating from the client.

I have gone through the differences between Reverse proxy and forward proxy. I think the above architecture is a forward proxy setup. But I am not sure. Also, I would like some suggestions as to how I can implement this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you wan't a forward proxy.
You can use :
nginx https://www.nginx.com/ or squid http://www.squid-cache.org/